# How to create a Cell link that interacts with Two Checkboxes

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I am working on an excel spreadsheet that would use two check boxes that would interact with on Cell-link. I have both of the check boxes created already, and they both are linked to the same cell. I am trying to create it so that both check boxes have to be clicked in order for the Cell-link to be "TRUE".

How can I go about this. If this involves using a bit of VBA, can I have an example of how to do this?

Comment: Why not have both link to different cells then have the third cell check that they are both true eg `=AND(A1,B1)`.  That way you don't need any code.

Comment: Thats a good idea! Let me try that out!